# Java когда читаю xml не получается обратиться к content

Tags: java, xml

У меня есть xml вида:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tasks>
    <task file_id="3406" cont_name="D:\Data\cont\con1.dat">
        <offset cont_offset="596672" file_size="16209"></offset>
        <offset cont_offset="3" file_size="5"></offset>
        <offset cont_offset="34534" file_size="3234"></offset>
    </task>
    <task file_id="3608" cont_name="D:\Data\cont\con2.dat"> 
        <offset cont_offset="39199605" file_size="101394"/></offset>
    </task>
    <task file_id="13435" cont_name="D:\Data\cont\con3.dat"> 
        <offset cont_offset="28936" file_size="14900"/></offset>
    </task> 
</tasks>
```

Мой код чтения xml:

```
        //Находим нужные параметры из task.xml------------------------------------------
        SAXBuilder parser = new SAXBuilder();
        org.jdom2.Document xmlDoc = parser.build(new File("D:\\Data\\task\\taskMas.xml"));
        
        //Получить все подэлементы <task>
        List children = xmlDoc.getRootElement().getChildren();
        Iterator i = children.iterator(); 
        
        while(i.hasNext()){ //Проход по всем подэлементам <task>
        
            Element nowTask = (Element) i.next();  //Текущий child элемента <task>

            String[] paramsXml = new String[2]; //Параметры для чтения контейнера
            System.out.println(nowTask.getName());
            
            //Параметры строчки <task...>
            paramsXml[0] = nowTask.getAttributeValue("file_id");       
            paramsXml[1] = nowTask.getAttributeValue("cont_name"); 
            
            //List из offset и отступов
            List<Content> offsetContent = nowTask.getContent();
            
        } //Переход на другую строчку
```

Я могу обратиться к root элементу tasks, и получить элемент task:

```
//Получить все подэлементы <task>
List children = xmlDoc.getRootElement().getChildren();
```

Потом через iterator я прохожу по элементам. И у меня есть текущий child элемента task

```
Element nowTask = (Element) i.next();  //Текущий child элемента <task>
```

Но я не могу никак достать из xml строчки, которые вложены в task

```
        <offset cont_offset="596672" file_size="16209"></offset>
        <offset cont_offset="3" file_size="5"></offset>
        <offset cont_offset="34534" file_size="3234"></offset>
```

Для этого я пробовал использовать

```
//List из offset и отступов
            List<Content> offsetContent = nowTask.getContent();
```

Но дальше не могу обратиться к Content как к Element чтобы достать атрибуты и значение. При этом я знаю, что эти вложенные строчки хранятся в nowTask как content. (см рис)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Подскажите как обратиться к этим вложенным элементам и достать их атрибуты? Может изначально, что-то делаю не так, подскажите как быть, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кривой `xml`:

```
<offset cont_offset="39199605" file_size="101394"/></offset>
```

Закрытая конструкция закрывается еще раз, должно быть так:

```
<offset cont_offset="39199605" file_size="101394"/>
```

или

```
<offset cont_offset="39199605" file_size="101394"></offset>
```

---

Получается:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tasks>
    <task file_id="3406" cont_name="D:\Data\cont\con1.dat">
        <offset cont_offset="596672" file_size="16209"/>
        <offset cont_offset="3" file_size="5"/>
        <offset cont_offset="34534" file_size="3234"/>
    </task>
    <task file_id="3608" cont_name="D:\Data\cont\con2.dat">
        <offset cont_offset="39199605" file_size="101394"/>
    </task>
    <task file_id="13435" cont_name="D:\Data\cont\con3.dat">
        <offset cont_offset="28936" file_size="14900"/>
    </task>
</tasks>
```

Я немного оптимизировал циклы:

```
// получаем все таски
for(Element task: xmlDoc.getRootElement().getChildren()) {
    System.out.println("Task: " + task.getAttribute("file_id"));

    // получаем все оффсеты этой таски
    for(Element offset : task.getChildren()) {
        System.out.println("    Offset: " + offset.getAttribute("cont_offset"));
    }
}
```